# How submit form when DropDownList has no value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm using

```
[Display(Name = "Anomaly_Assing_To_PA", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ActionPlan))]
public int assignToPA { get; set; }
```

in the form as this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("assignToPA", list, "-- Select to assign --", new { })
```

But when user didn't select a dropdown list item, form is not submitting. I guess that is because there is no value under "-- Select to assign --", so how can I add value to this in order to let the user select or not a value? for instance, 0 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try making the property nullable.

Comment: huh indeed, thanks dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your Drodownlist property Nullable like

```
public int? assignToPA { get; set; }
```